# Position the Popup control in the screen and Textblock text center

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm quite new in C# WPF. I want my Popup control to be positioned in a certain coordinates of the user's screen. and I want to make my textblock text center in the textblock itself. I tried to add a block but it doesn't work. Look at my XAML codes: (I'm 97% done in my personal project. :) )

Also, look at my screenshot, I put a red box there, I want my popup control to be there, although it is not my priority cause the original position is quite fine with me, but I would be glad if this will be moved.

Next, look at the annoying text, it is not centered.
The current position of the popup is in the left most and upper most part of my screen.

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="KeyLocks_Notifier.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Popup Name="Popup1" AllowsTransparency="True" PlacementRectangle="0,0,30,50" Placement="Center"
          PopupAnimation="Fade">
            <Border BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="50">
            <TextBlock Name="myPopupText"
                 Background="#FF9700FF"
                 Height = "40"
                 Width="180"
                 Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect/>
                </TextBlock.Effect>
            </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Please show your *actual* XAML generating that popup.

Comment: done, but I just pasted my codes on pastebin, because the xaml codes cannot be shown. I don't know why. probably because of the tags and the forum reads it not as a text.

Comment: You just have to format as code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the window :
In XAML there is a `WindowStartupLocation` on the root level with 3 options (Manual, CenterScreen, CenterOwner)

If you want a custom Location on your screen you need to set `WindowStartupLocation` to `Manual` and set the `Top` & `Left` with pixel

For your popup :
You can set the `Placement` to `custom`

[Example Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743607%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And for your text position [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828417/centering-text-vertically-and-horizontally-in-textblock-and-passwordbox-in-windo)

Comment: I already saw the link you gave about centering the text. It doesn't work. you see my codes above, there is already a border tag. Thank you though :)

Comment: Did you try the padding ?